# Нужно ли перекодировать данные в таблицах при изменении кодировки самой таблицы?

Tags: php, utf-8

Я переводил систему на UTF-8 с WINDOWS-1251, перешел хорошо все работает, только отвалился поиск.

Есть index.php (UTF-8) к нему подключается header.php (UTF-8) (формирует шапку где стоит форма поиска) в нем же происходит подключение search.js (UTF-8), который считывает запрос вводимый пользователем и запрашивает у search.php (UTF-8), который все это дело ищет.

Проблема в том, что после перехода перестал выводить данные из таблицы контактов, а из задач в поиск подставляет данные.

Не могу понять в чем причина.

Comment: Пробовали дебажить и смотреть что, во первых передает js в php, во вторых какой запрос php строит в mysql и что в конечном итоге отправляется обратно js скрипту?

Comment: @RifmaMan а вообще изменение у таблиц сопоставления на utf8_general_ci и у каждого столбца поставить utf8_general_ci достаточно для изменения кодировки содержимого этой таблицы?

Comment: @RifmaMan кстати, я поставил вывод консоль того что берется из формы, а в php файле возвращаю отправленный запрос. Все совпадает, никаких кракозябр.

Comment: Из чего следует что дело вовсе не в кодировке? Точно не скажу в чем проблема, но я бы еще сделал так, взял бы запрос mysql который строит php и прогнал его через phpMyAdmin к примеру, чтобы наглядно увидеть что ответ пуст и разобрался с синтаксисом mysql в том запросе. Касательно смены кодировки вы всё сделали верно.

Comment: @RifmaMan да вот интересно что до перехода работало все отлично.

Comment: Как на счет 1. заглянуть в базу в поля где происходит поиск и 2. попробовать поискать на латинице?

Comment: @RifmaMan нашел причину, но как ее поправить не знаю... у меня есть выборка поля таким образом if ($orders_input_check['status'] == 1 and $orders_input_check['vid_input'] == 'phone') {
   echo $orders_input_check['id']."<br>";
  } когда windows-1251 выводит, а когда в подключении базы ставлю настройку uft-8 не выводит.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76969/discussion-between-rifmaman-and-alexander-sizintsev).